# Custom property accessors in LitElement

Tags: javascript, lit-element, lit-html

In order to learn how to write custom property accessors, I am trying to create property accessors with the same behaviour as the default accessors. I am using the example from there docs [here](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#accessors-custom) but I am struggling to get it to work. The below causes an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. If I remove the getter and setter, the element works as expected and two divs containing "hello" and "world" are rendered.
How can I create custom property accessors for the property `data`, with the same behaviour as the default property accessors (where no getter and setter are defined)?

```
import { LitElement, html } from "lit-element";
import { render } from "lit-html";

class TestElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      data: { type: Array },
    };
  }

  set data(val) {
    let oldVal = this.data;
    this.data = val;
    this.requestUpdate("data", oldVal);
  }

  get data() {
    return this.data;
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = [];
  }

  render() {
    return html`${this.data.map(d => html` <div>${d}</div>`)}`;
  }
}
customElements.define("test-element", TestElement);

render(html`<test-element .data=${["hello", "world"]}></test-element>`, window.document.body);
```

I am trying to recreate the behaviour of this example, which renders "hello" and "world" as expected:

```
import { LitElement, html } from "lit-element";
import { render } from "lit-html";

class TestElement extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      data: { type: Array },
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = [];
  }

  render() {
    return html`${this.data.map(d => html` <div>${d}</div>`)}`;
  }
}
customElements.define("test-element", TestElement);

render(html`<test-element .data=${["hello", "world"]}></test-element>`, window.document.body);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
set data(val) {
    let oldVal = this.data;
    this.data = val; // THIS causes an infinity loop as you do invoke the setter again
    this.requestUpdate("data", oldVal);
}
```

Instead, set a different variable

```js
set data(val) {
    let oldVal = this.data;
    this.__data = val;
    this.requestUpdate("data", oldVal);
}

get data() {
    return this.__data;
}
```